# Mysterious process - RunSilent - error on Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2003

We are setting up production servers (Windows Server 2003 R2 64-bit) for a web application that uses the Dundas Maps for ASP.Net component.

After installation we receive the following error:
"RunSilent has encountered a problem and needs to close."

The question is, what on earth is RunSilent? A google search gets nothing of interest back. It appears to have nothing to do with Dundas. My guess is it has something to do with the graphic drivers.

Cheers - Chris

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://www.indigorose.com/forums/showthread.php?p=99273) which led me to [this](http://www.warmuskerken.com/).  Could it be some sort of timer running in the background?

Comment: Thanks for looking and congrats on your googling abilities, but this is  an out-of-the-box server 2003 instance with only the software we've specified on it. I'd be very surprised if it was this Timer Action Plugin software that was running on there.